# Homeomorphism from a certain space to $S^2$

Tags: general-topology, geometry

Consider the space
$$ X = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^4 : x_1,x_2,x_3\geq 0,x_1+x_2+x_3=1,x_1x_2x_3=x_4^2\}. $$
It is not hard to see that $X$ can be decomposed as the union of two copies of the standard simplex $\Delta_2$ glued along their boundaries, and thus that $X$ is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^2=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^3:y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2=1\}$.  Is there a nice, tidy formula for a homeomorphism $f\colon X\to S^2$?

Note that the group $G=S_3\times C_2$ acts on $X$, with $S_3$ permuting the first three coordinates, and $C_2$ acting via $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\mapsto(x_1,x_2,x_3,-x_4)$.  The same group acts on $S^2$, with $S_3$ permuting the coordinates and $C_2$ acting via reflection across the plane $P$ where $y_1+y_2+y_3=0$.  Ideally $f$ should be equivariant for these actions.  That would force $f(x)$ to be in $P$ whenever $x_4=0$, and $f(1,0,0,0)=\pm(2,-1,-1)/\sqrt{6}$ and $f(1/3,1/3,1/3,1/\sqrt{27})=\pm(1,1,1)/\sqrt{3}$, for example.

Comment: Your reflection in $S^3$ sends $$ \begin{align}  (y_1,y_2,y_3)\mapsto \frac13(&y_1-2y_2-2y_3,\\&y_2-2y_1-2y_3,\\&y_3-2y_1-2y_2). \end{align} $$ Not sure if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\Delta=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mid x_i\geq 0,x_1+x_2+x_3=1\}$$ and $$\Delta_0=\{(x_i)\in \Delta\mid x_1x_2x_3=0.\}$$

Let $\mathbf c=(1/3,1/3,1/3).$ Given $\mathbf x\in \Delta,$ $\mathbf x\neq \mathbf c,$ there is a unique $t=t(\mathbf x)\geq 1$ such that $\mathbf  c+t(\mathbf x)(\mathbf x-\mathbf c)\in\Delta_0.$ Then send $$h(\mathbf x)=\begin{cases}\mathbf 0&\mathbf x=\mathbf c\\\frac{\mathbf x-\mathbf c}{t(\mathbf x)\|\mathbf x-\mathbf c\|}&\mathbf x\neq \mathbf c \end{cases}$$

Show $h$ is continuous.

$h$ is a homeomorphism of $\Delta$ to a disk of radius $1$ in $P$ which commutes with $S_3.$

Define:

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=h(x_1,x_2,x_3)+\operatorname{sign}(x_4)\frac{\sqrt{1-\|h(x_1,x_2,x_3)\|^2}}{\sqrt3}(1,1,1)$$

This will be your function.

---

Let $x_m=\min x_i$ then you need $\frac13+t(x_m-\frac13)=0$ or $$t(\mathbf x)=\frac{1}{1-3x_m}$$

You also need to prove that $h$ is continuous at $\mathbf x=\mathbf c.$

You can rewrite $h$ as: $$h(\mathbf x)=\begin{cases}\mathbf 0&\mathbf x=\mathbf c\\\frac{(1-3x_m)(\mathbf x-\mathbf c)}{\|\mathbf x-\mathbf c\|}&\mathbf x\neq \mathbf c \end{cases}$$ It is a little easier to prove this is continuous, since for $\mathbf x\neq\mathbf c,$ $$\|h(\mathbf x)\|=1-3x_m\leq 3\|\mathbf c-\mathbf x\|$$

This also gives a slightly easier formula for $f,$ since $\|h(x)\|=1-3x_m,$ so:

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=h(x_1,x_2,x_3)+\operatorname{sign}(x_4)\sqrt{2x_m-3x_m^2}(1,1,1)$$

---

The key is that the two spaces are both homeomorphic to the suspensions of two topological disks, $\Delta_0$ and the unit circle $C$ on $P.$ Both $C$ and $\Delta$ are acted on by $S_3,$ topological like a dihedral group. The natural action of $C_2$ on the suspension of any space corresponds to the actions of $C_2$ defined for these sets.

We only really need a homeomorphism of $\Delta_0$ and $C$ which agrees with the action of $S_3$ on each.

The homeomorphism from $\Sigma C$ to the unit sphere is defined first as a continuous function on $C\times [-1,1],$ defined for $\mathbf y\in C, t\in[0,1]$ $$(\mathbf y,t)\mapsto \mathbf y\sqrt{1-t^2}+\frac{t}{\sqrt3}(1,1,1).$$

This function factors through the quotient function, and that factorization gives the homeomorphism.

The case for $X$ being homeomorphic to the the suspension of $\Delta$ is slightly more complicated, but not much more.